# Have integer added to end of array if larger than rest of integers in array

Tags: javascript

My function goes through an array to find the lowest index it should be inserted into. I am assuming the array is always sorted. It works unless the integer is larger than the rest of the array integers. At this point, it needs to be added to the end of the array.

I tried to use if else statements and have the number appended with a `push` but it just goes into a never-ending loop since I will always stay less than `arr.length`. I tried adding a `break` after the push inside the else but then, it always appends without inserting into the correct position if there is a place inside the array for it already.

```
function lowestIndexInsert(num,arr){
  for (i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
      if (arr[i]>num){
      arr[i]=num;
      }
      else { 
        arr.push(num);
        break;
      }

  }
 return arr.indexOf(num);
}


lowestIndexInsert(15,[8,25,33,52,70]);// should return 1
lowestIndexInsert(80,[8,25,33,52,70]);// should return 5
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your question. Do you wanna add `num` at the correct position or only add if at the end of the array it `num` is larger as any entry in `arr` ?

Comment: I would like to do both. Let's say it iterates it and num can be put at arr[2] then that's where it will be. If the number is larger than all the numbers in the array is where I'm having trouble.  It should be put onto the last spot in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to insert an element to the array and then instantly break. Once this is done you can catch the final case where i = length and hasn't been inserted yet. If you use 3 arguments such as: `.splice(start, deleteCount, insertMe)` the function will insert the item at the specific index and delete none. With this you can do:

```js
function lowestIndexInsert(num,arr){
  for (i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
      if (arr[i]>num){
          arr.splice(i, 0, num);
          // Break here to stop the loop after inserting
          break;
      }

      // Perform a final check to see if the item was inserted.
      if(i == (arr.length - 1)){
          arr.push(num);
      }

  }
 return arr.indexOf(num);
}


lowestIndexInsert(15,[8,25,33,52,70]);// should return 2
lowestIndexInsert(80,[8,25,33,52,70]);// should return 5
```

Comment: if its splice into the array it doesn't look like it'll be in the correct spot or am not looking at this correctly?

Comment: actually running the code for the second example it returns -1 and not 5 like it should

Comment: I checked the code with `consol.log` and the second `if` is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate as many times as the original array was long, you have to remember what that length was.  That's what variable are for.

Also, you don't know if you need to add to the array until you have *finished* searching it.

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing inside the loop, so you'll get your new value pushed once for every single number in the array that's greater than the value. That's not what you want.

You can greatly simplify this code, and avoid manual loops altogether:

```
function lowestIndexInsert(num,arr) {
    let index = arr.length;
    arr.some((value, i) => {
        if (value > num) {
          index = i;
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
    arr[index] = num;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't push anything into the array though

Comment: Sure it does. Because index starts at `arr.length`, if no spot in the array matches the criteria, it'll instead set the value at the end to `num`, which is equivalent to a `arr.push(num)`

Comment: this does do the trick but it is not returning the index of where it is being put into.

Comment: @SunnyNoeun If you need that, you can just add `return index;` to the end of the function.